# Holomorphic tangent bundle of a polydisk

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, complex-manifolds

I find this statement in an article but I don't fully understand it.

"If $V$ is a polydisk in a connected complex manifold then $T_bB$, where $b\in V$, is the quotient of the complex vector space $\Gamma(V,T^{1,0}B)$ of holomorphic vector fields on $V$ by the subspace $I=\{\gamma\in\Gamma(V,T^{1,0}B)|\gamma(b)=0\}$."

Lectures on deformations of complex manifolds
(Deformations from differential graded viewpoint)
Marco Manetti

Thanks for all help me.

Comment: The general idioms are: (i) Every $(1, 0)$ tangent vector at a point of a polydisk extends to a holomorphic vector field (e.g., a constant field). (ii) Two vector fields take the same value at a point if and only if their difference is zero. <> Consequently, the set of values of a vector field at one point (i.e., the holomorphic tangent space) may be identified with the indicated vector space quotient.

Comment: Thanks u. Have u got a reference for them?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking: Is any part of the comment not apparent from knowledge of linear algebra?

Comment: Maybe I don't fully understand ii).

Comment: I ought to have written: Two vector fields take the same value at a point $b$ if and only if their difference is zero at $b$.

Comment: Ah ok, but this is obvious.